# What is equivalent to serialPort.ReadExisting() in Windows 10 app?

Tags: c#, encoding, serial-port, uwp, windows-10-universal

I have used SerialPort class in my previous desktop application where I was using following method to read response from SerialPort

```
 var response = serialPort.ReadExisting();
```

Now I am implementing same thing in Windows 10 app using following method

```
 public static async Task<string> ReadAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken,DataReader dataReaderObject)
        {
            string response = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                var flag = false;
                Task<UInt32> loadAsyncTask;
                uint readBufferLength = 1024;
                cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                dataReaderObject.InputStreamOptions = InputStreamOptions.Partial;
                loadAsyncTask = dataReaderObject.LoadAsync(readBufferLength).AsTask();

                UInt32 bytesRead = await loadAsyncTask;
                if (bytesRead > 0)
                {
                    byte[] bytes = new byte[bytesRead];
                    dataReaderObject.ReadBytes(bytes);
                    //response = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);
                    // response = Convert.ToString(bytes);
                   response= ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                response = string.Empty;
            }
            return response;
        }
```

But , looks like I am getting response in different encoding format.
When I copied both responses in notepad++ I found following difference:

[image]
What is going wrong here? 
 What is equivalent to serialPort.ReadExisting() in Windows 10 app?

Comment: It would help if you can paste legacy SerialPort code. What bytes are your sending?

Answer (score 0):

The `SerialPort.ReadExisting Method ()` returns the contents of the stream and internal buffer of the `SerialPort` object as a string, so the equivalent to `ReadExisting()` in Windows 10 app should be [DataReader.ReadString | readString method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.streams.datareader.readstring.aspx).

But it's OK to use [DataReader.ReadBytes | readBytes method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.streams.datareader.readbytes.aspx), problem is how to convert the byte array to string. The byte here uses uint8 encoding, it is possible you can get string like this:

```
Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
```

You can refer to a Japaneses [blog](http://garicchi.com/?p=16171), it writes ASCII encoding data but still need to read as UTF8.